# Unable to install RealmSwift via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cocoapods

i'm at OSX 10.11.2, Cocoapod 0.39.0, and I'm trying to install RealmSwift on my app. However this error occurs:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `RealmSwift`
```

Here's my Podfile by the way:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'RealmApp' do
 pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do your run pod install with --no-repo-update?

Comment: Yeah I did, same problem though. :(

Comment: That's odd. RealmSwift is in the master repo of CocoaPods. Could you share the output of `pod repo`?

Comment: Running `pod setup` rather than using a custom source might help in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! I had to specify another source since it can't find it under Cocoapod.

Here are the changes I made:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Realm', :git => 'http://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
    pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'http://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'swift-2.0'
end
```